# Versioning hardware vendor SDK with git

Tags: git, version-control, third-party-libraries

We have `n` C projects which reference 4 different versions of a device SDK - `12.3`, `13.1`, `15.0`, and `15.2`. There is no public upstream repo for the SDK - it is released as a `zip` file. We need to patch the SDK to work for our particular needs, and would like to minimize copy-paste code sharing.

I would like to put the SDK versions in a `git` repo to share the current state of our patches between our `n` projects. My plan is to put all SDK versions as branches from a (mostly) empty `master` branch.

Is this a common best practice? If not, what is the common best practice for tracking local changes to unversioned 3rd party code, with dependencies on several releases?

Comment: Sounds like broadcom SDK...

Comment: [Here](https://gist.github.com/datagrok/8577287) is an interesting Blog post about this. It is a bit of a rant, but if your take the time and read **the comments** to it, you will probably find some good recommendations there.

Comment: @DocBrown I had read that (_and_ the comments) the day before posting this, which was one of the factors influencing the solution I've proposed in my question :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it would be reasonable to store them as branches that way. It would even be worth tagging the original releases so they're super easy to get to. I would also suggest creating the branches as orphans or at least not having a dummy empty master branch.